# Class as parameter

Tags: class, mono, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm currently trying to implement a Logger.

```
public class Logfile
{
    public static Logfile getLogfile(class _classTogetLoggerFor)
    {

    }
}
```

The main idea is, that every class gets it's own logger, where options like loglevel,etc can be set individualy. But the code above is not working, so how can I set a Class as parameter in Mono (c#).

Thank you for your help ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Type`:

```
public static Logfile getLogfile(Type _typeToGetLoggerFor)
```

and then:

```
var logger = Logfile.getLogfile(typeof(SomeClass)); // or just call GetType()
```